# How do I read part of a file into a DataFrame with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have text files which look like this:

```
    0.289
--------
A B C D E
--------
EBA
E-D
EB-
EED
EBD
EBE
E-D
E-D
```

Now I want to read the various bits into data structures.

I want to learn how to use dataframes, so I want to open the file read the first value into a float, skip a line, read the next line into a built in list, then skip a line and read the rest into a dataframe.

The file reading routines for dataframes seem to work on the whole file, so not sure how to do this.

You must also be able to add rows to a dataframe, I just don't know how to do it and the documentation is so extensive - which is good - but I'll need to read 50 pages to find the answer...

Edit: I can do it like this, but there must be a nicer way:

```
alignmentMatrix = []
with open("DataFile.txt", 'r') as f:
    theta = f.readline().strip()
    f.readline()
    alphabet = f.readline().split()
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        row = list(line.strip())
        alignmentMatrix.append(row)
alignmentDF = pandas.DataFrame(alignmentMatrix)
```

And so I end up with this:

```
    0  1  2
0  E  B  A
1  E  -  D
2  E  B  -
3  E  E  D
4  E  B  D
5  E  B  E
6  E  -  D
7  E  -  D
```

So it's a 2D dataframe.

Comment: After those two f.readline()'s, you can just do `df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None)` It will only take the remaining rows. I don't know your actual file so I'm not sure about the strip() part, but after the two lines you don't need another loop.

Comment: See above, that doesn't quite give me what I want.  I should have said I need the string values separated out into chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot be better than in your example for the first bits. However, you can read the remainder as fixed width file (pandas.read_fwf):

```
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    theta = float(f.readline().strip())
    f.readline()
    alphabet = f.readline().split()
    f.readline()
    alignmentDF = pandas.read_fwf(f, widths=[1,1,1], header=None)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that does it.